# Teradata SQL: How to create a new column that lists unique column values?

Tags: sql, teradata, teradatasql

If I have the following table:

```
PART_NO             CUSTOMER            QTY
1001                JII                 2
1001                MTH                 3
1002                JII                 7
```

How can I write a query to return the following:

```
PART_NO     QTY             CUST_CNT            CUST_LIST
1001        5               2                   JII, MTH
1002        7               1                   JII
```

I tried the following query but it's not working:

```
SELECT 
    PART_NO, 
    SUM(QTY) AS QTY,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CUSTOMER) AS CUST_CNT,
    TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM LISTAGG(CUSTOMER, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CUSTOMER)) AS CUST_LIST
FROM 
    table_name
GROUP BY 
    PART_NO

[Teradata Database] [3706] Syntax error: Data Type "CUSTOMER" does not match a Defined Type name.
```

I essentially want to return the PART_NO, sum of the QTY column by PART_NO, count of unique CUSTOMER, and the unique CUSTOMER values listed.

Comment: nPath is currently the most efficient way to get this result, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/71239743/2527905

Answer (score 0):

You have a complex `customer` expression:

```
    TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM LISTAGG(CUSTOMER, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CUSTOMER)) AS CUST_LIST
```

Delete that line and the query will work fine, as it is basic SQL-92.

---

Consider replacing it with XMLAGG.
[LISTAGG equivalent in Teradata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29510654/listagg-equivalent-in-teradata)

You're going to want to use valid syntax.
Both examples and syntax are described in the
[documentation](https://docs.teradata.com/r/4hkdo4nmM%7Ef1eM4Sp2Nw4w/xRa2DYkSptcdXbkiEX_g2Q).

Comment: I tried updating the query and I got the following error: `[Teradata Database] [3706] Syntax error: expected something between the word 'CUSTOMER' and ','.`

Comment: Syntax would be `XMLAGG(CUSTOMER||',' ORDER BY CUSTOMER)` but nPath is better.