# Combine rows in Teradata SQL if a id field appears more than once

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

I'm trying to go from the first picture to the second picture.  Basically, if the Concatenated field appears more than once do to there being 2 or more reps attached to the identifier, show all the names in a new column, if there is only one rep then return that one name

My initial query:

```
SELECT
NA.SoldToNbr
, NA.DivCd
, NA.Mgmt_Rep_Nm
, concat(NA.SoldToNbr,' ',NA.DivCd) RepIdConcat
FROM NA
WHERE NA.SlsOrgCd = 1000000
AND NA.MgmtRepNbr <>  00000000
AND NA.Mgmt_Rep_Nm not like '(AGENCY%'
AND NA.Mgmt_Rep_Nm not like '(DEADWOOD%'
AND NA.Mgmt_Rep_Nm not like '(CPTS%'
AND NA.Mgmt_Rep_Nm not like '(TEMP%'
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
```

Is there a way to do this in Teradata SQL?
Pictures are attached here:
[Sample return for initial query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXPHG.png)
[Desired end result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwMyQ.png)

I've tried using XMLAGG but keep getting the storage limit exceeded error

```
SELECT DISTINCT
NA.Sold_To_Desc
, NA.DivCd
, NA.Mgmt_Rep_Nm
, concat(NA.ShipToNbr,' ',NA.DivCd) RepIdConcat
,    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(RepIdConcat) > 1 THEN TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM TRIM(TRAILING ' ' FROM (XMLAGG(TRIM(NA.Mgmt_Rep_Nm) ORDER BY NA.Mgmt_Rep_Nm) (VARCHAR(10)))))
        ELSE MAX(NA.Mgmt_Rep_Nm)
    END AS CombinedRepValues
FROM NA
WHERE NA.SlsOrgCd = 1000
AND NA.MgmtRepNbr <>  00000000
AND NA.Mgmt_Rep_Nm not like '(AGENCY%'
AND NA.Mgmt_Rep_Nm not like '(DEADWOOD%'
AND NA.Mgmt_Rep_Nm not like '(CPTS%'
AND NA.Mgmt_Rep_Nm not like '(TEMP%'
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4;
```

Comment: Use NPATH. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71220502/list-of-unique-values-instead-of-count-teradata-sql/71239743#71239743